# Google container engine, direct access to pods

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to deploy multiple identical docker containers on Google Container Engine. I am using kubectl for that following the instructions here: https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/hello-node

The instructions describe how to run a redundant service managed by the load balancer, so when I contact the balancer, it sends my request to one of my redundant pods. And in that mode, it works fine.

But I need to do this differently. I need to be able to contact individual pods directly from the client. So I am trying to use --type=NodePort with my "kubectl expose deployment" command:

```
mac-124307:hellonode ivm$ kubectl expose deployment hello-world --type=NodePort --port 9000 --target-port 9000
service "hello-world" exposed

mac-124307:hellonode ivm$ kubectl get service
NAME          CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
hello-world   10.15.253.149   <nodes>       9000:30513/TCP   21m
kubernetes    10.15.240.1     <none>        443/TCP          46m
```

The command does not complain, and I can use "gcloud compute instances list" to see external IP addressed of individual pods:

```
mac-124307:hellonode ivm$ gcloud compute instances list
NAME                                          ZONE           MACHINE_TYPE   PREEMPTIBLE  INTERNAL_IP  EXTERNAL_IP     STATUS
gke-hello-cluster-default-pool-402030b2-j60q  us-central1-a  n1-standard-1               10.128.0.3   104.197.72.212  RUNNING
gke-hello-cluster-default-pool-402030b2-q86r  us-central1-a  n1-standard-1               10.128.0.4   35.192.4.43     RUNNING
gke-hello-cluster-default-pool-402030b2-tf7t  us-central1-a  n1-standard-1               10.128.0.2   146.148.72.137  RUNNING
```

but when I try to connect to port 9000 at any of these IP addresses, my connection times-out.

```
mac-124307:hellonode ivm$ curl http://104.197.72.212:9000/
... <time-out>
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you opened up port 9000 in the Google Cloud Firewall?

Comment: routing traffic directly to pods defeats some of the designing principles in k8s. What are you trying to achieve by reaching the individual pods directly?

Answer (score 2):

Note that the node port that was allocated is `30513`. You are using `9000`, that's the port for the ClusterIP, `10.15.253.149` that was assigned.

You also need to have port `30513` open on the firewall, as suggested by Eric.

If you only need a one-off access to this pod, you can also use `kubectl port-forward name-of-a-hello-pod 9000` which will forward `127.0.0.1:9000` on your workstation directly to the pod. Of course this only works as long as `kubect port-forward` is running.